# Caching images in expo is thowing Failed to load assets error in production

Tags: react-native, caching, expo, production

[image: 1]

This is my code to cache all the images in my local folder. I'm prefetching all the images and after that resolving the promise. But this always results in "Failed to load all assets" error in Expo production mode.

```
 function cacheImages(images) {
  return images.map((image) => {
    if (typeof image === "string") {
      return Image.prefetch(image);
    } else {
      return Asset.fromModule(image).downloadAsync();
    }
  });
}
async function _loadAssetsAsync() {
    try {
      imageAssets = cacheImages([
        require("./ASSETS/Mariodimarko.jpg"),
        require("./ASSETS/SAMMY_WFX.jpg"),
      ]);

      await Promise.all([...imageAssets]);
    } catch (error) {
      console.warn(error);
      await Promise.all([...imageAssets]);
    }
  }

  return ready? (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <AuthProvider>
          <StackNavigator />
      </AuthProvider>
    </NavigationContainer>
  ) : (
    <AppLoading
      startAsync={_loadAssetsAsync}
      onFinish={() => setReady(true)}
      onError={(error) => console.warn(error)}
    />
  );
```

Comment: Did you guys manage to find a solution? I'm stuck on this error

Answer (score 0):

You are not defining your **imageAssets** or if you did out of the function, probably it was defined as **const**. This is generating an exception catched by your code.

Just add the keyword **const** before **imageAssets**

```
...
    try {
      const imageAssets = cacheImages([
        require("./ASSETS/Mariodimarko.jpg"),
        require("./ASSETS/SAMMY_WFX.jpg"),
      ]);

      await Promise.all([...imageAssets]);
    } catch (error) {
      console.warn(error);
      await Promise.all([...imageAssets]);
    }
...
```

Comment: The error is still showing even after adding const. Any help would be a great help 

Answer (score 0):

If your paths to the images really exists, the only reason that i can imagine is due the dev enviroment. Let's try this:

```
const cacheImages = (images) => {
  return images.map(image => {
    if (typeof image === 'string') {
      return Image.prefetch(image);
    } else {
      return Asset.fromModule(image).downloadAsync();
    }
  });
};

const _loadAssetsAsync = async() => {

  const myImages = {
    a1: { asset: require("./ASSETS/Mariodimarko.jpg") },
    a2: { asset: require("./ASSETS/SAMMY_WFX.jpg") },
  };

  let arrayImages = [], assetInfo;

  for (const key in myImages) {

    assetInfo = await Asset.fromModule(myImages[key].asset);

    console.log(assetInfo); // just for you see the info

    if ( ( assetInfo.dowloaded ) && ( assetInfo.localUri !== null ) ) {
       /* this never happens in development mode even you 
       added the path to your app.json (assetBundlePatterns)
       and if it was previously downloaded in production mode, 
       you dont need to download it again,right?
       */
    }
    else {
       /* here we add the remote url to the arrayImages */
       arrayImages.push(assetInfo.uri);
    }

  };

  if ( arrayImages.length > 0 ){
    const imageAssets = cacheImages(arrayImages);
    try { await Promise.all([...imageAssets]);} 
    catch (error) { console.warn(error); }
  } 

};

    const [ready, setReady] = useState(false);

    if (ready) {
      return (
        <NavigationContainer>
          <AuthProvider>
            <StackNavigator />
          </AuthProvider>
        </NavigationContainer>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <AppLoading
          startAsync={_loadAssetsAsync}
          onFinish={() => setReady(true)}
          onError={(error) => console.warn(error)}
        />
      );
    }
```

Comment: I'm sorry but still, it's showing the same error. Because of this, the standalone app is not opening. It is stuck on a blank white screen.